# Output from `pg_dump --schema-only` has inconsistent order

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, collation, pg-dump

I'm trying to compare schemas between 2 (identical) databases using `pg_dump --schema-only` in PostgreSQL 9.3.9, but the diff of the output shows the ordering is inconsistent for two triggers:

```
2896c2896
< CREATE TRIGGER audit_trigger_row AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON model_run FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func('true');
---
> CREATE TRIGGER audit_trigger_row AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON model FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func('true');
2900c2900
< CREATE TRIGGER audit_trigger_row AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON model FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func('true');
---
> CREATE TRIGGER audit_trigger_row AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON model_run FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func('true');
```

It seems the ordering is getting mixed up between `model` and `model_run` because of the underscore character.  [A previous question/answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115364/why-does-postgres-order-by-seem-to-halfway-ignore-leading-underscores) seems to indicate the `collate` value may be the culprit.  [A post on *nabble.com*](http://postgresql.nabble.com/Comparing-two-PostgreSQL-databases-order-of-pg-dump-output-td4751332.html) makes me think this is a somewhat-known issue.

- Does the `collate` value of the DB affect pg_dump's sorting of the **schema** output (ie, not just the data)?
- If I re-create the DBs using `lc_collate='C'` will that force a standard ordering for non-alphanumeric characters?

Below is the current list of the 2 databases:

```
gcis=# \l+ gcis_21*
                                                   List of databases
     Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges | Size  | Tablespace | Description 
--------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+-------+------------+-------------
 gcis_2180    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                   | 35 MB | pg_default | 
 gcis_2190    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                   | 35 MB | pg_default |
```

*Footnote:* The schema comparison is actually being done automatically on the fly through [Module::Build::Database from CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ebduggan/Module-Build-Database-0.57/lib/Module/Build/Database.pm).  The full command being used is 
`pg_dump -xOs -E utf8 -n $database_schema $database_name`
Though `utf8` is explicitly passed as the encoding here, the database itself
is also currently UTF8.

Comment: Huh, yeah. I think `pg_dump` should be using `COLLATE "C"` in queries. What's the collation of each database? Please show output of `\l+ thedatabasename` in `psql` for both.

Comment: @CraigRinger I was just looking back at this question, and realized I never pinged you back after I added the `\l+ thedatabasename` output you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name, data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
ORDER BY table_schema, table_name, ordinal_position;
```

- SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name, data_type: Specifies
  the columns to be selected in the query result. These include the
  table schema, table name, column name, and data type.
- FROM    information_schema.columns: Specifies the table from which to
  retrieve the column information. In this case, it's the columns table
  in the information_schema schema, which stores metadata about
  database objects.
- WHERE table_schema NOT LIKE 'pg_%': Filters out    any    tables
  whose schema starts with 'pg_'. This is done to exclude    system
  tables typically found in the PostgreSQL system schemas.
- ORDER BY    table_schema, table_name, ordinal_position: Sorts the
  results first    by table schema, then by table name, and finally by
  the ordinal    position of the columns within the tables.

Comment: If you wish to help, perhaps you may want to consider adding some sort of an explanation to your code fragment, which would show how it works and how it addresses the problem. As it stands, it's unclear how this catalog query helps with the `pg_dump` output ordering.